# Package NodeJS Dependencies with C# Nuget Package

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to bundle NodeJS/Npm dependencies in a Nuget Package without including the entire `node_modules` folder? I am looking for maybe a post-install hook, where when a user installs the package, a command is automatically triggered to run `npm install` in the respective folder. Does something like this exist in Nuget/C#? Or am I better off compiling it all into a single file and using that in my project instead (via NodeServices)?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can do that but there is a way for you to run npm install when you build your solution by edit your csproj file like this

```
  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this out and get back to you.